# Is there any way to create a responsive calendar and have a checkbox on each day so that number of days are calculated in a number field

Tags: apex, visualforce, calendar

Is there a way to create a custom calendar with dates checkbox so that if we just click on the check boxes the number of days are automatically calculated in another number field. For example as in the image below the 6th and 17th are checked so the number of days field should be updated as 2.

[image]

Comment: If you haven't done so already, please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask]. This question reads like a request for someone to do your work for you.

Comment: @ Adrian Larson, I have used the lightning calendar and created a calendar with adding a custom object to it i am able to see added records on the calendar however i want to count the number of days.